# Wordpress theme development: Possible to have main theme files in subfolder?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm developing a theme locally and using Gulp to run tasks. My theme directory structure looks like this:

```
  |- theme folder/
      |- app/
          |- css/
          |- fonts/
          |- images/ 
          |- index.html
          |- js/ 
          |- scss/
      |- dist/
         |- optimized files from app/
         |- all other standard WP theme files and subdirs
      |- gulpfile.js
      |- node_modules/
      |- package.json
```

When WordPress loads the theme, I see a blank screen, which is to be expected. WP looks for the theme files in the top-level directory of the theme folder. Is it possible to point directly to the dist folder? If it helps, I'm using Flywheel for my local dev setup.

Answer (score -1):

`index.php`, `style.css` (the main stylesheet where you declare theme's metadata), `header.php` and `footer.php` need to be placed in the root of your theme's folder. Every other files (assets, includes, et cetera) can live in their own subdirectory.

For more details, please read: [Organizing Theme Files | Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/organizing-theme-files/).